# problem in creating *.conf file in conf.d folder on nginx server. Not able to deploy the angular project

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, nginx-config, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ubuntu 20.04 lts instance in aws

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /home/ubuntu/project/exam-portal-front-end;
    server_name 3.7.56.77;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I have written the above code in 3.7.56.77.conf file conf.d directory.
My angular project is not able to deploy on the server.

Comment: I don't have any domain name. So in my case how to create a file in the conf.d directory